# cakephp conditions based on HABTM relation

Tags: php, cakephp

User Model has relation:

```
public $hasMany = array(
'MyRecipe' => array(
'className' => 'Recipe',
)
);
```

I want to select all users who have recipes with `ID: 1,2`

How I can use that conditions in select:

```
$this->User->find('all', array(
 'conditions' => array(
 'Recipe.Id' => [1,2]
)
));
```

But in this example I will get also Users without recipes, how to prevent that ?

Comment: `$this->User->find('all', array(
 'conditions' => array(
 'Recipe.Id IN' => [1,2]
)
));`  or   `$this->User->find('all', array(
 'conditions' => array('OR'=>['Recipe.Id'=>1,'Recipe.Id'=>2]
)
));`

Comment: Please tell us (or add a tag) saying which CakePHP version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please give this relation in User model

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'User';
    var $belongsTo = array("Recipe");
}
```

and in user controller your query as

```
$list = $this->User->find('all',array("conditions"=>array("recipe_id IN"=>  [1,2] )));
```

its gives output which you want..